# How can i hide a preview of a video in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kinda trying to build my first website atm. I was trying to create a button that would start a video if it was pressed (that already works), but i don't want a preview of the video if the button wasn't pressed. How can i hide the video before the button is being pressed?

Comment: If you want your video to keep its size but hide the content before playing it, you can use CSS `opacity` prop by setting the initial value to `0` and updating that value to `1` on button click (just before playing the video)  (or using `visibility` = `hidden` / `visible`). For further help, please include your code (or the smallest part necessary to reproduce) in your post (runnable, if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Put a `style='display: none'` attribute in the video tag element. And then, in the botton's click handler, insert this `document.getElementById("your-video-element-id").style.display = 'block';` in order to make it visible.

For a similar example look here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp